# How can I streamline images and screenshots I embed into my post?

Tags: discussion, faq

Uploading 1MB images or even 300KB images in a question or answer is often unnecessary/overkill and slows down page loads significantly especially when viewing on a mobile connection. Similarly, really large dimensions are often pointless due to real-estate restrictions.

**How can I keep file sizes down or adjust the dimensions of the images to reasonable and sensible numbers?**

Comment: Thanks for the information! Could you edit it to be more like a question and answer pair? Don't forget you can answer your own questions! The question could be something like "how can I optimize the images I embed into my post?". Then your info fits perfectly as an answer.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Good point and done.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't have the wherewithal to *optimise* an image prior to upload, here are a few tips on doing so directly on AnimeSE:

After embedding an image to your post, you should see an imgur URL similar to https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOSov.png (just using this as an example). This should result in a large image (190KB, a relatively reasonable size, but even this can be optimised further):

[image: ...and Another one!]

But this image can now be optimised even further simply by tweaking the URL being used. For example tweaking the URL to `https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOSovt.png` (note that the filename now has an **t** (for small **thumbnail**) at the end) will result in an image of smaller size and dimension:

[image: ...and Another one!]

This file is only 3.5KB in size and also smaller in terms of dimensions.

If the dimensions are unsuitable add an **m** (for **medium** thumbnail) or an **l** (for **large** thumbnail) instead. This will result in the following images respectively:

1. [image: ...and Another one!] (9.7KB)
2. [image: ...and Another one!] (25.7KB)

Other options that also appear to work are:

- b (**Big** square crop) [image: ...and Another one!] (38 KB)
- h (**Huge** thumbnail (1024x1024)) [image: ...and Another one!] (190KB)
- s (**Small** square cropped thumbnail) [image: ...and Another one!] (15.6KB)

(I have no idea why the "square thumb" image is ~5KB larger than the "medium" one.)

---

If you'd nevertheless prefer viewers to be able to view your uploaded image in all its raw glory, simply link an optimised image to it by wrapping the code like this:

```
[![...my optimised image!][2]][1]
```

This will link the thumbnail to the original source file, like so:

[image: ...my optimised image!]

In other words, those wanting to view a higher resolution `[1]` can do so by simply clicking on the thumbnail `[2]`.

---

If these options are too complicated, just blindly add an *l* to the image filename in your post. This should display it in large dimensions and still load fast.

I should also note that anime/cartoon images generally tend to be more optimisable than photographs, etc.

Comment: Where can I see the documentation for these options?

Comment: This is incredible ...

Comment: @iKlsR http://api.imgur.com/models/image

Comment: @looper :) thanks